# Два Django проекта и одна база данных

Tags: python, django

Есть два проекта на Django (`project_s, project_c`), оба подключены к одной БД (`project_db`).

если авторизоваться в приложении `project_c`, то в `project_s` этого не произойдет.
Как можно решить этот вопрос?

Для чего это надо:
`project_c` будет разворачиваться у разных людей(условно), получать из их личной БД(`user_db_n`) необходимые данные и записывать в таблицу `project_s`.
После чего необходимо передать идентификатор этой записи в view приложения `project_s`, для дальнейшей обработки(с проверкой - имеет ли право этот пользователь делать запрос данных) и возврата данных обратно `project_c`.
Возможно конечно я изобретаю велосипед.

При попытке проделать такое методом POST получаю `Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)`

---

можно конечно сделать нечто такое(на стороне `project_s`):

```py
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def pub_request(request):
    if request.POST['id_requests']:
        id = request.POST['id_requests']
        return JsonResponse({'id':id})
    return JsonResponse({'id':None})
```

Но что-то мне подсказывает это не верным решением.

Comment: вопрос не до конца понятен, но походит на то что если нужен общий механизм аутентификации для двух разных приложений то в голову приходит [Single Sing On](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)

Comment: @MikhailLazko Т.е. Необходимо чтобы пользователь который авторизовался на `project_c`, имел беспрепятственный доступ к `project_s` (т.е. авторизовался и тут). Для того, чтобы передать информацию из view `project_c` в view `project_s`. Возможно есть более правильные методы общения разных проектов с одной базой.

Comment: скорей речь идет не про авторизацию, а про аутентификацию, какой способ аутентификации пользователей у вас в проекте, сессионные куки?

Comment: для правильно выполнения запроса и того чтобы не нарваться на CSRF надо передавать заголовок x-csrftoken

Comment: @MikhailLazko стандартно через `path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'), name='login'),`. А по поводу >правильного выполнения запроса, я понимаю что надо передать токен, но как это сделать?

Comment: запрос делаются через браузер клиента или от сервера к серверу напрямую? просто читаю уже несколько раз описание вопроса, но так и не пойму что происходит. если у вас используется одна база и сессионые куки которые хранятся в базе все что нужно для того чтобы пройти аутентификацию, предоставить ид сессии. сессия либо есть в браузере пользователя или если запрос с сервера то значит есть доступ к базе и сессии тоже. от того откуда идет запрос будет зависеть решение

Comment: @MikhailLazko На сервере поднят проект `project_s` с `default` базой `project_db`, 
где-то в "каком-то городе" поднят проект `project_c` c `default` базой `project_s.project_db`.  

В проекте `project_c`, получают необходимые данные из **не** `default` базы, 
после чего данные необходимо передать в проект `project_s`, обработать и вернуть результат `project_c`.  

Я пытался сделать это `POST` запросом используя `requests`, не удачно.

Comment: если запрос инициируется пользователем и он известен, то берем сессию пользователя и его csrf token подкладываем эти заголовки в запрос и отправялем `request.session.session_key` 
 `cookies={settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME: session_key}` -> https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#cookies